# Table column is not expanding at expected on firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

Hello I need a fluid table with other div in the same line. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/wp1j605s/2/) you can see a fiddle where I could do what I want, which works perfectly on Chrome. The problem is when I try it on Firefox. The column width is the minimum, it is not expanding as in Chrome.

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: lightgray; overflow: auto;">
  <div style="height: 200px; overflow-y: auto; margin-right: 300px; float: left;">
    <table border="1" style="">
      <theader>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th style="width:100%">Name</th>
          <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
      </theader>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td style="word-break: break-all">Dan</td>
          <td>00:00:00.000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td style="word-break: break-all">Bob</td>
          <td>00:00:00.000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td style="word-break: break-all">Jenn</td>
          <td>00:00:00.000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #65de4f80; width: 300px; height: 200px; margin-left: -300px; float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

REmove float : left and also the overflow: auto on top you don 't need

```
<div class="container" style="background-color: lightgray;">
  <div style="height: 200px; overflow-y: auto; margin-right: 300px;">
    <table border="1" style="">
      <theader>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th style="width:100%">Name</th>
          <th>Time</th>
        </tr>
      </theader>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td style="word-break: break-all">Dan</td>
          <td>00:00:00.000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td style="word-break: break-all">Bob</td>
          <td>00:00:00.000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td style="word-break: break-all">Jenn</td>
          <td>00:00:00.000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div style="background-color: #65de4f80; width: 300px; height: 200px; margin-left: -300px; float: left;"></div>
</div>
```

Regards

Comment: But the second div is not at the same line of the table [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/109h7mkz/)

Comment: sorry i dont understand good, add display: flex; on container  class="container" style="background-color: lightgray; display:flex;"